# Does the MacBook Pro backlit keyboard impact battery life?

Tags: keyboard, macbook, battery, battery-life, backlight

Hey, quick question, I love the backlit keyboard feature on my MacBook Pro (13", just in case it matters) and tend to have it on half-way even when it's not that dark. However, I have no idea how much this feature is draining the battery.

Can anyone tell me what kind of impact the backlit keyboard has on battery life? Obviously it can't be too severe, but I assume it isn't negligible either.

Comment: Did you ever try the suggestion by radius?

Answer (score 1):

A tool such [iBatt](http://raynersoftware.com/ibatt/) can help you to compare how much power is used when backlit is on and when it's off.